# Display value from other table

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a database with two tables.
The first table contains an foreign key from the second table. 
In my MVC-project, i would like to display the value (stored in second table) instead
of only the ID from the first table..

In SSMS i could do this with a join. But how do I do this in c#?

```
rec.Title = item.Title + " - " + item.AppointmentLength.ToString() + " mins" + " BehandlingsID " + ***item.BehandlingarId***;
```

//

***item.BehandlingarId*** contains the ID which i would like to change to its corresponding value.

These are my two tabeles:

```
public class AppointmentDiary
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }     

        public DateTime DateTimeScheduled { get; set; }

        public Behandlingar Behandling { get; set; }

        public int? BehandlingarId { get; set; }
    }


public class Behandlingar
    {
        public int BehandlingarId { get; set; }
        public string Namn { get; set; }
        public int Pris { get; set; }
        public int Tid { get; set; }
    }



List<DiaryEvent> result = new List<DiaryEvent>();
                foreach (var item in rslt)
                {
                    DiaryEvent rec = new DiaryEvent();                      
                    rec.EndDateString = item.DateTimeScheduled.AddMinutes(item.AppointmentLength).ToString("s");
                    rec.Title = item.Title + " - " + item.AppointmentLength.ToString() + " mins" + " BehandlingsID " + item.BehandlingarId;

                }
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you instantiate "item"? From what you have, it is difficult to know if item is a DbContext or ...? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, have a look above!
The code is from a free plug-in-thingy so i guess its allright to post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting something like this?

```
var result=AppointmentDiary.Where(i=>i.BehandlingarId==BehandlingarId).ToList;
```

This will give you the records that matches the `BehandlingarId` in `AppointmentDiary` table

Edit :

If you want the other way around.

**If DB is your datacontext**

```
var result=DB.Behandlingar.Where(i=>i.BehandlingarId == BehandlingarId).FirstorDefault().Nam;
```

**Note:** BehandlingarId here is the foreign key from AppointmentDiary.

say you want to access the `nam` for BehandlingarId=1 then

```
var result=DB.Behandlingar.Where(i=>i.BehandlingarId == 1).FirstorDefault().Nam;
```

will give you the first record that matches the `BehandlingarId==1` in the `Behandlingar` table

You can put this snippet any where you want to access the `nam`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I think i want it the other way around..I can acess BehanligarID in the AppointmentDiary-table but i would like to get the records from the Behandlingar-table..Its the string Namn i want back..

Comment: Thank you! Im gonna try this one out!

Comment: Do you mind having a look at my edit again? I cant figure out where to put the snippet?

Comment: @user2915962 can you post how you are accessing the database. Are you using EntityFrameWorks? Because from your posted code its really difficult to understand how you are accessing the database.

Comment: Yes, i am using entity framework. I acces the DB appointmentDiary with this instance:

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me! The thing is that i have a dropdown-list deciding which Nam i would like to display. The way it is now, the ID is getting sent and not the value from the other table.